# Updating lifecycle configuration with filters for S3 bucket fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Java SDK to manage my S3 buckets. At this point in time, I want to introduce a new use case for this bucket i.e. I want to store similar objects but with a different retention period. I learnt that I can set lifecycle policies by prefix. I want to use this convenience provided by S3 to have a different lifecycle configuration for the new objects I am storing in my bucket identifiable by a different prefix.

Here is my Java program that does this:

```
package com.something.aws.s3;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.BucketLifecycleConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.lifecycle.LifecycleFilter;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.lifecycle.LifecyclePrefixPredicate;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class S3ClientTest {
    private AmazonS3 s3;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getBuckets() {
        for (Bucket b : s3.listBuckets()) {
            System.out.println(b.getName());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_addPrefixRules() {
        String bucketName = "test-bucket";
        BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule rule = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule()
                .withId("new-lifecycle-id")
                .withExpirationInDays(1)
                .withFilter(new LifecycleFilter(new LifecyclePrefixPredicate("remote/")));
        List<BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule> bucketLifecycleConfigurationRules =
                s3.getBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName).getRules();
        bucketLifecycleConfigurationRules.add(rule.withStatus(BucketLifecycleConfiguration.ENABLED));
        BucketLifecycleConfiguration updatedBucketLifecycleConfiguration =
                new BucketLifecycleConfiguration().withRules(bucketLifecycleConfigurationRules);
        s3.setBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName, updatedBucketLifecycleConfiguration);
    }
}
```

My test test_addPrefixRules tries to fetch all lifecycle config rules defined for a bucket, add my new rule for the prefixed objects and update the bucket with the new set of rules.

When I run this, I run into the following exception:

```
 com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Filter element can only be used in Lifecycle V2. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequest; Request ID: 6E24BE84B13B6440; S3 Extended Request ID: Y5VyIEuXcbGVBoddgdT7TVVa670dU6V1v5Oizlq/UU2pSDNjiAxyzrc155uf0MTfZxPw1GyUvGM=)
, S3 Extended Request ID: Y5VyIEuXcbGVBoddgdT7TVVa670dU6V1v5Oizlq/UU2pSDNjiAxyzrc155uf0MTfZxPw1GyUvGM=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1639)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4325)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4272)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.setBucketLifecycleConfiguration(AmazonS3Client.java:2326)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.setBucketLifecycleConfiguration(AmazonS3Client.java:2293)
    at com.appdynamics.eum.aws.s3.S3ClientTest.test_addPrefixRules(S3ClientTest.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I found very little documentation and discussion in forums that can explain this error. Can someone help me out in understanding what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: It tells you that you are using a filter in the wrong life cycle.

Comment: @lajos-arpad True. Can you elaborate on that please? When am I actually supposed to use it?

Comment: "Filter element can only be used in Lifecycle V2." (whatever that means)

Comment: Yes. What that means is what I am struggling to find out.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown in case you have both `Prefix` and `Filter` base tags in a single Lifecycle policy. These tags cannot be combined within a single policy. There is a possibility that your existing policy already has some `Prefix` base tags and is therefore throwing an error when you are trying to add a new rule with `Filter` base tag.

One possible workaround is to wrap the `Prefix` base tags with `Filter` tags.

Reference: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=812878